# Analytic solution to the following system of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-fields

Is there a smooth vector field $u: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $$
\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t}u +\lambda\left(u \times \bigtriangledown u\right)  =   \mu \bigtriangleup u.~~~~~~~~~\lambda\neq 0~~~~~\mu >0 $$ with initial condition $$u(x,0) = u_0(x).$$ The operation $\times$ is the usual cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So equivelently, \begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial }{ \partial t}
\begin{bmatrix}
 u_1 \\
u_2 \\
 u_3
\end{bmatrix}
+ 
\lambda\begin{bmatrix}
 u_2 \dfrac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}-u_3 \dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}  \\
u_3\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} -u_1 \dfrac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\\
  u_1\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}- u_2\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} 
\end{bmatrix}
= \mu \bigtriangleup \begin{bmatrix}
  u_1  \\
   u_2 \\
   u_3 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Here $\bigtriangleup $ is the Laplacian operator and $\bigtriangledown u$ is the gradient of $u$ given as $\bigtriangledown u = \left[\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1},\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2},\dfrac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\right]$. So for example, $\bigtriangleup u_1 = \dfrac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_1^2}+ \dfrac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_2^2}+ \dfrac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_3^2}$.

Comment: Probably not, unless this is one of those "fully integrable" nonlinear PDE's solvable by means of the Inverse Scattering Transform. But that's a research-level question more suitable to Math Overflow than M.SE.

Comment: Would you clarify the $\nabla u$ term? It appears to mean $(u_{1,1}, u_{2,2}, u_{3, 3})$.

Comment: I am also interested in the uniqueness and existence. I will post there also.

Comment: @A rural reader. Sorry for delay I clarified the gradient. But it should have been obvious from the context. You are correct in the use of Einstein notation though they both are the same.